# 【Rails】acts_as_paranoid environment, I want to physically delete records that use the relation dependent: :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### detail

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid
  belongs_to :user
```

users_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  user.destroy!
end
```

When a user is deleted, how should I describe that the user is logically deleted and the post related to the deleted user is physically deleted?
I would like to ask for your wisdom.

### environment

rails 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it in the `after_destroy` callback?

Looking at the docs I don't see a paranoid equivalent of `destroy_all!` so you're going to have to do a loop and fall `destroy_fully!` (which is what paranoia does so this will be no slower [src](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia/blob/032a2ad4df8e623b6a276edd22305ef3b63b5b91/lib/paranoia.rb#L145))

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_paranoid
  has_many :posts
  after_destroy :delete_deps

  def delete_deps
    self.posts.each do |post|
      post.destroy_fully!
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: nlta,thankyou!  When I wrote the code you gave me, I got this error. 「rescue500 => NoMethodError : undefined method `destroy_fully!'」I've also used destroy_fully! in other places, but it seems to cause an error when used in this section.

Comment: def delete_deps
    self.posts.map(&:destroy_fully!)
  end

Comment: thankyou for teach me!

Comment: @katahik, nice you found basically the same solution as I did. I've updated my post. Please accept the solution if the problem is solved. Happy to help!